# Query Warns to Update Api to 2.0 when 2.0.1 is in use

Tags: web-services, api, rest, rally

When executing a RallyRestApi.Query call that returns without erro, but with no results (when there should be at least one), warns of using an old version of the API.  We have downloaded the new version and can see that 2.0.1 is loaded, yet the above behaviour persist.

Any ideas what could be causing this warning and what might be the corrective steps?

Is this a known issue?

Comment: Which REST toolkit are you using? The Java REST toolkit? Can you post an excerpt of your code, especially where you new up the restApi?

Answer (score 0):

Two different version numbers are relevant here: one is the version of DLL, the other is the version of WS API.

2.0.1 is the latest version of Rally REST API for .NET DLL, available [from here](https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitFor.NET).

The warning you mention is WS API deprecation warning.  The latest veresion of WS API in production is v2.0. The one before it is 1.43, which will not be supported after June of this year per [this schedule](https://help.rallydev.com/web-services-api-deprecation-policy)).

If you are still getting the warning, check what version of WS API your code is using when `RallyRestApi` is instantiated - perhaps it is still set to 1.43 or below.

WS API version is normally set as follows, even though the latest dll will default to v2.0:

```
restApi = new RallyRestApi("user@co.com", "secret", "https://rally1.rallydev.com", "v2.0");
```